# Validate request using API key from div on external website

Tags: jquery, validation, iframe, curl

Hi dear StackOverflow friends.

I'm trying to solve a quite complex solution I have to develop for the company for which I'm working. I have developed an electrical energy calculator in JavaScript and it is located on our own web server as a webpage with a complete DOM (`html`, `head`, `body` and lots of ".css" and ".js" files included).

The problem is that the calculator has to be a part of our customers web page (in a `div`) where it loads the calculator from our web server. When the company website requests the calculator it has to take a secret API key with the request to our domain that validates the customer and sends the calculator back to the customer with the right view that the customer has payed for.

I have tried an "IFRAME" and it works great but there is no way to send a "SECRET" api key with the request (the company web page needs to be a .html file):

```
<iframe src="http://localhost/calc/energycalc.php"  
        width="815" 
        height="572" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="no" 
        style="border-radius: 7px;">
</iframe>
```

Also, I have read that iframes are to be avoided so I'm looking for something else.

Now I'm working on a solution where the request order looks like this:

> Company website -> company website api folder with secret key in a
>   .php script -> our webserver -> return calculator to company .php
>   script -> return calculator to company website.

I have tried a couple of jQuery solutions. This ajax call comes from the companies website where the div has an id called 'siteloader' the makes a ajax call to the api folder (which is also located on the companies website) which has an .php script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/customer/api/key.php',
    dataType: 'html',
success: function(data) {
    $('#siteloader').html($(data));
    }});
```

The key.php script does a cURL request with the secret key as a POST parameter:

```
$api_key = "9chuPsWJBSpbiphxgxF3ld9pSWQQIEj5dPEkbstj0YReumqQ06"
$url = 'http://localhost/calc/energycalc.php' // our web server
$post_params['key'] = $api_key

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$reply = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $reply;
```

This is not working properly - it does not return any styling.

Please ask if there is something that needs clarification (which there probably is)!

Anyone that has any input on how to solve this problem or improve my solution?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I'm following your logic, but let me try to re-state things. You're shooting off an AJAX request to a key.php page on the client's server? And then that key.php page is shooting off a curl request to your remote web server?

Could your jQuery AJAX call just send a request to your remote server? it would pass the secret API key over to the server and receive back the template that you want to drop in place on the clients page? Your server would then validate the API key and act accordingly. If the API key is invalid, then you would send back a 401 (Unauthorized) to the jQuery request and just display a message or do nothing (your choice).

There are a lot of applications that handle things this way (Google Analytics, Disqus, Stackoverflow, etc).

Update: You should look at the "data" option of the [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method. It allows you to send, obviously, data (your API key) over to the server. You could also embed that in to the URL of the request.

**Examples**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/server.php",
  data: { key: "yoursecretkey" }
})
  .done(function( response ) {
    alert( "response back: " + response );
  });
```

or something using the URL:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "/server.php?key=yoursecretkey" });
```

Comment: Hi Bryan. Thanks for you reply. The answer to your first question is 'Yes', but this is just something I'm testing out and can change. I'm not quite understanding when you say "... It would pass the secret API key over to the server and receive back the template that you want to drop in place on the clients page?". Could you elaborate on your idea? Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer to, hopefully, provide a little more information for you to follow.

Comment: Hi again and thanks for your update. The secret key must be stored server side and can not be visible in the JavaScript code to anyone loading the page - the secret key is a secret!

Comment: You have to send the key from the client to the server somewhere though. If you don't have access to a database on the  client-side database to store the key, then the only option I can see is to store it in text.

Possibly using a specific IP address. But this is going beyond the scope of the question. You asked how to send keys, not to encrypt and store client-side key data.